# Avoid using dynamic from clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, clause

How can i avoid using dynamic from clause? Even if i don't know the database name, i prefer to use a static statement, like this:

```
    select *
    into   #tempTable
    from   @DBName.Invoices
    where  InvoiceId = 5.
```

I got this error:  *Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near '.'.*

I need to use  *select into*  clause because the column names may be different from each databases;

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do? You can't select from an object held in a variable without using dynamic sql.

Comment: Unfortunately only dynamic sql will help. You may create your own proc or use unsupported sp_MSforEachDB http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/08/27/60700.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you will have to use dynamic SQL for this, see below for an example

```
Declare @DBNAME NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'xxx'
Declare @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) ='select *
into   #tempTable
from   ' + @DBName + '.Invoices
where  InvoiceId = 5.'

execute sp_executesql @SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can i avoid using dynamic from clause? Even if i don't know the database name, i prefer to use a static statement

SQL wont accept columnnames,tablenames,databasenames as parameters.so unless you you avoid them,you cant avoid dynamic sql..

Change your query to dynamic sql to avoid error..But again you will have a problem with temp tables scope

--This will fail ,because temp table falls under different scope

```
Declare @sql nvarchar(4000)
set @sql='
select *
    into   #tempTable
    from   @DBName.Invoices
    where  InvoiceId = 5'
```

---one option is to use global temp tables

```
declare @dbname varchar(1000)
set @dbname=db_name()

declare @sql nvarchar(4000)
set @sql='select *
    into   ##tempTable
    from   '+@DBName+'.dbo.test_Delete '
    exec(@sql)
    select * from ##temptable
```

But be carefull with above approach,since above temp table have global scope..

You also can use Openrowset ,some thing like below

```
select * into #temp from openrowset
('SQLNCLI','Server=yourinstancename;Trusted_Connection=yes;', 'select * form table')
```